# How to use Event Bus to communicate between any component in nuxt js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

So here I have a notification list page, if I click 'mark all read', the number of unread notifications in the header should decrease, I've tried to use the bus event, but nothing has changed

[image]

`Headers.vue`

```js
mounted() {
  this.$root.$on('ReadAllNotif', (art) => {
    this.totalUnread = art;
  });
},
```

`Notification.vue`

```js
methods: {
  ReadAllNotification() {
    this.$root.$emit('ReadAllNotif', []);
  },
}
```

is there any other way of unrelated 2 component communication?

Comment: You could debug it easily by using a `console.log(art)` just before the `this.totalUnread = art;` line and see if it's get there. If it does, your method is working great. Meanwhile, I do recommend to use Vuex rather than event bus which is more a hack and not really a good practice for serious projects.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion dude, it turns out that now there is a 1 step error when calling api 'mark all read', this was caught when I added console.log (art)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The OP solved it's issued by finding out that the actual error was coming from the API and not the event bus.